# How do I modify a pcap file with python?

Tags: python, sip, wireshark

I'm trying to anonymize SIP Traces by replacing all the phone numbers with random ones. I'm able to read the file and the numbers from it. What I can't do however is modify the file without corrupting it. 
I've tried different parsers (pyshark, dpkt & scapy) and they're all great for reading the file. Modifying doesn't work however.

What I've tried:

1. "Brute Force" by just reading in the file, modifying it and saving
   it as .pcap again. This obviously didn't work at all and Wireshark
   complained about the file being cut short (which it was (probably for character reasons?)).
2. All the parsers. The problem with these is that I can read the file but I can't write to it without turning it all into a string which again, breaks the file.

Is there some kind of function in one of the libraries where I could replace a pattern with another one? Or do any of you have an idea of how I could solve this differently?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: You are probably using the parsers wrong. If you open a file using scapy's `rdpcap()` and do some changes, you'll need to write it back using `wrpcap()`. You shouldn't convert it to text at anytime. See https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#importing-and-exporting-data

Comment: In case you want to try something else besides scapy, I highly recommend the freely available Tracewrangler tool, written by Jasper Bongertz, for this purpose.  You can find it here: https://www.tracewrangler.com/.  That tool, and others, are also listed at https://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools.

Comment: Agree with Christopher. This is the exact use case for Tracewrangler. Keep in mind that it's Windows-only though.

Comment: @Cukic0d I can't change the text because it will complain about not being a string. Do you know what I can do or where I can find some more information about wrpcap()?

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard that tool looks great but I need to do it automatically in Python

Comment: @Cukic0d If I tried subbing it gives me "cannot use string pattern on bytes-like object", I don't understand why though.